# sheetjs xlsx, How to write merged cells?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs

I need to create a xlsx with merged cells using sheetjs.

**data**:

```
[
  {
    "id": "nick",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "ball"
      },
      {
        "name": "phone"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "jack",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "pen"
      },
      {
        "name": "doll"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**My code:**

```
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "");
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', type:'array'});
saveAs(new Blob([wbout],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), filename + ".xlsx");
```

**The result I want to get:**

[image: result]

How do I get this result?

... Thank you

Comment: i am also expecting the lib will create the desired sheet with the given json object. but it seems the nested array is not treated well..will get back when find a solution. for now information i got from google., it seems client need explicitly specify the merge row/column.

Comment: Hi chacker did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 49):

```
const merge = [
  { s: { r: 1, c: 0 }, e: { r: 2, c: 0 } },{ s: { r: 3, c: 0 }, e: { r: 4, c: 0 } },
];
ws["!merges"] = merge;
```

Use this code for merge A2:A3 (`{ s: { r: 1, c: 0 }, e: { r: 2, c: 0 } }`)
and A4:A5 (`{ s: { r: 3, c: 0 }, e: { r: 4, c: 0 } }`)

Here s = start, r = row, c=col, e= end

Comment: I'm wondering what are s and e for? which are key of { r: n, c: n} in merge array, Is it randomly named keys?

Comment: @JillAndMe s = Start, e = End, r = Row & c = Column. I think it is not randomly named. ref. https://docs.sheetjs.com/

Comment: It's only works using the down to the top order. Por exemplo, first row 10 then the row 5 .... row 0.

Comment: there is a way to make this dinamically?

Comment: @Carlost yes you can dynamically create the array with your own logic